# computing minima of chunks of a vector: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r

I want to gather all minimum non-zero values of runs of a vector that are separated by zeros. So the results of applying my code to the vector `x` below must be `-1, -9`: -1 from the `-1, 5` and -9 from `-4, -9`.

I am running the code below and I get the following message:

> Error in if ((temp[i] == 0) && (temp[i + 1] != 0)) { : 
>   missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

```
x <- c(0, 0, -1, 5, 0, 0, -4, -9, 0)
temp = c()
minV = c()
for (i in 1:length(x)-1){
    temp[i] <- x[i]
    if((temp[i] == 0) && (temp[i+1] != 0)){
        minV <- c(minV,min(temp))
        temp <- c()
    }
}
minV
```

What can I do to achieve my goal?

Comment: looks like on of the logic checks results in `NA`. see what value of `i` it stops on, then check what the if statement resolves to for that value of `i`. Then figure out why it's resolveing to NA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So there are several issues in the code as follows;

1. You are trying to evaluate temp[i+1] when it has not been created yet this will result in NA.
2. Because you are indexing using i, after you free temp in the middle of the loop when it encounters a zero, it will not add value to beginning of temp instead it will add in the middle.
3. When looping you are looping on `1:length(x)-1` which will result in 0 to 8 instead you want to make it `1:(length(x) - 1)`

Here's a fix of the code;

```
# Creating data
x <- c(0, 0, -1, 5, 0, 0, -4, -9, 0)

# Create temp place holders
temp = c()
minV = c()

# Loop on x vector
for (i in 1:(length(x)-1)){
  # If x[i] is not zero
  if(x[i] != 0){
    # Append to temp
    temp <- c(temp, x[i])

    # If next value is zero then get minimum
    if(x[i+1] == 0){
      # Get minimum
      minV <- c(minV, min(temp))
      # Free temp
      temp <- c()
    }
  }
}
minV
# -1 -9
```

A better way however is to cut the vector whenever it encounters a zero then get the minimum of each of the splits as follows;

```
# Creating data
x <- c(0, 0, -1, 5, 0, 0, -4, -9, 0)

# Split string at occurances of zeros
ll <- with(rle(x == 0),{
  ifelse(x == 0 & (seq_along(x) != cumsum(lengths)[lengths <= 3 & values]), NA, x)
})
x_split <- split(x, with(rle(is.na(ll)), rep(1:length(lengths), lengths) + ll * 0))

# Get minimum of each vector as list of minimum(s)
lapply(x_split, min)
# $`2`
# [1] -1
# 
# $`4`
# [1] -9

# Or get it in form of vector
unlist(lapply(x_split, min), use.names = FALSE)
# [1] -1 -9

# Or use sapply automatically [credit to Ben Bolker]
sapply(x_split, min)
# [1] -1 -9
```

Comment: I like your solution. (1) it's too bad there's not a more compact way to do the splitting; (2) why not use `sapply()` for the last step?

Comment: Good point regarding sapply I have added it to the solution. With regards to splitting well I have thought of another way where I convert it into a string then cut the string then reconvert it into vector as well but I think both require multiple steps. If you know a better solution please share it.

Comment: A simpler version of the same general idea: `minV <- tapply(x, with(rle(x == 0), rep(seq_along(lengths), lengths)), FUN = min);
minV[minV != 0]`

Answer (score 4):

The `:` operator has lower precedence than `-`.  That means that `1:n - 1` is the same as `seq(0,n-1)` rather than `seq(1,n-1)`.

Comment: I think the main reason why not to use min(x) automatically is that he/she wants to treat each section of the vector separated by zero individually and get the minimum of each.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another alternative if it helps?

```
x <- c(0, 0, -1, 5, 0, 0, -4, -9, 0)

accumulated.values <- NULL
min.values <- NULL

for (value in x) {

  # if we hit a 0
  if (value == 0) {

    # and we have some values accumulated 
    if (!is.null(accumulated.values)) {

      # calculate the minimum value of the accumulated values
      min.values <- c(min.values, min(accumulated.values))

      # clear the accumulated values 
      accumulated.values <- NULL
    }

    # otherwise ignore
  }
  else {

    # add the value to the accumulated list
    accumulated.values <- c(accumulated.values, value)
  }
}

min.values
# [1] -1 -9
```